# jna Active window process name for x64

Tags: java, 64-bit, jna

I get all needed information for x86 programms (in C:\Program Files (x86)) without any problems with below statement. But for x64 empty result for activ window process name. Is it possible detect active window process name (.exe path) for x64 processor with jna?

- Eclipse Luna for x64
- Windows 8 pro x64
- JRE8 x64
- jna 4.1.0

---

```
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.Kernel32.OpenProcess;
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.Kernel32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION;
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_READ;
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.Psapi.GetModuleBaseNameW;
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.User32DLL.GetForegroundWindow;
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.User32DLL.GetWindowTextW;
import static your.pack.name.EnumerateWindows.User32DLL.GetWindowThreadProcessId;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

public class EnumerateWindows {
    private static final int MAX_TITLE_LENGTH = 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char[] buffer = new char[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];
        GetWindowTextW(GetForegroundWindow(), buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
        System.out.println("Active window title: " + Native.toString(buffer));          

        PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), pointer);
        Pointer process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
        GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
        System.out.println("Active window process: " + Native.toString(buffer));
        System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());

    }

    static class Psapi {
        static {
            Native.register("psapi");
        }

        public static native int GetModuleBaseNameW(Pointer hProcess, Pointer hmodule, char[] lpBaseName, int size);
    }

    static class Kernel32 {
        static {
            Native.register("kernel32");
        }
        public static int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
        public static int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

        public static native int GetLastError();

        public static native Pointer OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, Pointer pointer);
    }

    static class User32DLL {
        static {
            Native.register("user32");
        }

        public static native int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND hWnd, PointerByReference pref);

        public static native HWND GetForegroundWindow();

        public static native int GetWindowTextW(HWND hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) expects a pointer to 32 bits of memory.  You're giving it a pointer to a pointer, which is 32 bits or 64 bits depending on your platform.  You're then passing a 64-bit value to [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), which expects a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

i get all information for x86 and x64 software without any problem, if i export my project to runnable jar.
Above problem affect only on, if i run the project from Eclipse